# Python - Why I can not pass the attribute as a argument for another method inside the class?

Tags: python, class

```
class Node:
    """A Tree Node with 3 attributes: l_child, r_child and data"""
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.data = val
        self.l_child = None
        self.r_child = None

class BST(object):
    """Implement a Binary Search Tree class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        print "Initial root", self.root

    def insertRecur(self, node, data):
        if node is None:
            node = Node(data)
        else:   
            if data < node.data:
                insertRecur(node.l_child, data)
            if data > node.data:
                insertRecur(node.r_child, data)

    def Insert(self, data):
        self.insertRecur(self.root, data)
```

Sorry, guys
this is actually what my original code is. I want to use Python to implement a binary search tree class. and I want to do like that

```
test = BST()
test.Insert(1)
print test.root
```

and test.root is `None`

Comment: `self.data` haven't value assignment on any place

Answer (score 2):

Of course it will still be `None`. You didn't assign it the value. Should be.

```
def Insert(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.Recur(self.data, data)
```

However, the function

```
def Recur(self, node, data):
    if node is None:
        node = data
```

achieves absolutely nothing (and never did) because `node` is not used anywhere, only assigned to.

EDIT: After your updated code, we can see what you're trying to do. The reason your `test.root` is `None` is because you never assign it. The problem is here:

```
def insertRecur(self, node, data):
    if node is None:
        node = Node(data)
```

When this function is called from `self.insertRecur(self.root, data)`, it is POINTING to the same value as `self.root` which is `None`. When you do `node = Node(data)` you are reassigning `node` to point to `Note(data)`, this does not reassign `self.root`. Do this instead :

```
class Node:
    """A Tree Node with 3 attributes: l_child, r_child and data"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.l_child = None
        self.r_child = None

class BST(object):
    """Implement a Binary Search Tree class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()
        print "Initial root", self.root

    def insertRecur(self, node, data):
        if node.data is None:
            node.data = data
        elif data < node.data:
            node.l_child = node.l_child or Node()
            self.insertRecur(node.l_child, data)
        else:
            node.r_child = node.r_child or Node()
            self.insertRecur(node.r_child, data)

    def Insert(self, data):
        self.insertRecur(self.root, data)
```

Comment: If the OP uses your edits, what *exactly* does the resulting code accomplish? `Recur` still has no meaning in that case!

Comment: @jpaugh Yes, I am aware of that. I just answered his question on why there was no `example.data` and was pointing that out to him that `Recur` does nothing. I didn't change it cause I don't know his intention in that method.

Comment: Ok. My downvote was a little harsh. I made a minimal edit so that I could retract it.

Comment: Sorry, I change the example code to the original one. I want to implement a BST

Comment: @user2341963 Thanks, Man! But I still did get the idea why your code works compared with mine. `self.root = None` vs `self.root = Node()` What is the topic for these things that I can take a deeper look? Thanks

Comment: @JasonYuan I think your problem comes in from how you understand the way python passes parameters. You should check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) post. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You just assign the value of `self.data` to `node`, not the `variable self.data` itself. What you called in `Insert` function is exactly:

```
self.Recur(None, 5)
```

I guess what's you  wanna is:

```
self.Recur(*self.data, 5)
```

But there's no `pointer` in python. You can merge the code of `Recur` into `Insert`, or if you wanna maintain both `Recur` and `Insert`:

```
    def Recur(self, node, data):
        if node is None:
            node = data
        return node

    def Insert(self, data):
        self.data = self.Recur(self.data, data)
```

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. I just switch back and forth from C++ and Python. Little bit confused!

Answer (score 0):

Your example *would* work in some programming languages. (For example
`C` allows this, via pointer references.) The reason it doesn't work here is because of how the semantics of method-calling is defined in Python.

#### Name binding in Python

When you write

```
self.data = None
```

this assigns a new name (`self.data`) to the object `None`.

With `self.Recur` defined as

```
def Recur(self, node, data):
    if node is None:
        node = data
```

the following gives a new name to `None` in the context of the `Recur` method:
`node`.

```
self.Recur(self.data, data)
```

However, this new name (`node`) in the inner scope for the same object has no co-relation to the other name (`self.data`) in the outer scope.

When you write

```
node = data
```

this assigns the name `node` to a new value, namely the value to which
the name `data` refers. Again, this does not affect the name
`self.data`. For more information, check out this [blog post](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/).

#### How to do what you want

On the other hand, if you want `Recur` to be able to assign a value to any attribute of the `test` object, it can be done. Here
is one way to achieve it:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

    def Recur(self, nodeName, data):
        if self[nodeName] is None:
            self[nodeName] = data;

    def Insert(self, data):
        self.Recur("data", data) 

    __getitem__ = self.__getattr__
    __setitem__ = self.__setattr__
```

**NB: This code is untested**

This allows `Insert` to choose the name (`"data"`) to which `Recur` assigns a value. `Recur`, for its part, uses the dict-key get-item syntax of Python to assign a value to the key `data` in our quasi-dict object; however, we set the get-item and set-item semantics to be the same as the get-attribute and set-attribute semantics with the last two lines — this ensures that `self["name"]` means the same thing as `self.name`. A less mysterious implementation would be:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.__getattr__(key)
```

Comment: Note: I edited the code to add the `__setitem__` line, which is critical to get right.